# Is $L^p$ for $0<p<1$ quasi-normed?

Tags: lp-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $L^p$ be a topological vector space of measurable functions $f$ such that $\int |f|^p\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$, and define $$||f||_p := \left( \int |f|^p\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/p}.$$ Is this a quasi-norm? That is, does there exist $K>0$ such that for $f, g\in L^p$ we have $$||f+g||_p \leq K(||f||_p+||g||_p)?$$

Context: By setting $$[f]_p = \left( \sup\limits_{\alpha>0} \alpha^p\mu(\{x : |f(x)|>\alpha\})\right)^{1/p}$$ we define $f$ to be weak $L^p$ if $[f]_p<\infty$. Then $[\cdot]_p$ is a quasi-norm for $0<p<\infty$. It would be nice if the same would hold for $L^p$.

Comment: This question shows insufficient context and effort

Comment: What kind of context do you expect?

Comment: suggested reading: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Please stop the incessant editing of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the inequality $(a+b)^p\leq a^p+b^p$ and the convexity of $x\mapsto x^{1/p}$ for $0<p<1$.